# Can I light the sides of a netherrack block on fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building a house in the over world made entirely of netherrack. I want it to be very bright, as in, you look into the distance and see the sun on the horizon, but its not the sun, its my flaming house.

The only problem is that I cant light the sides of the netherack blocks on fire, if I click on the side of the block with a flint and steel nothing happens. I want flames to lick up the sides of the netherrack and stay on fire, like when you light the sides of wooden planks on fire.

I drew a picture to make it easier to understand:

[image]

Is there anyway to light the sides of netherrack on fire? If not, are there any alternatives to making my house *look* on fire?

Comment: Yet another one of those titles...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Netherrack will not burn on the sides. From my personal experience, the only items that burn on the sides are items that will be consumed by fire.
You could make your walls stair-stepped and light each step to get that effect, but that would likely make your house much wider than you were planning.

Answer (score 1):

If your house is made of flammable materials then you could create a Glass Dome. if your house is stone or anything else you can skip the dome.

after than drop lava down so it coats the house, this wont get you the flame effect and it'll make your house larger especially if you use a glass dome but you get your light level from the lava just like with fire and it adds a extra defense against mobs who follow you back. you can stop the lava from spreading on the ground by making a 1 block moat around the outside for the lava to fall into.

otherwise if you are just after a far off marker for your house at night you can go with a Beacon, you'll see it more than fire since the pillar goes into the sky and should be visible the moment the chunk is loaded.

Comment: The problem with beacons is you need to kill the wither

Comment: @imulsion not a problem in creative mode however because i couldn't assume the OP was in that mode or not i left it to last

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making the wall columns like this:
fire
netherack
fire
netherack
ect...

You can also make patterns, such as a checkered one if you feel like having no 2 blocks touch.
Remember that mobs can attack through the fire, so add some protection.

Comment: Could also do it in a checkered pattern if you feel like having no 2 blocks touch.

Comment: @Batophobia Edited